# proof/explanation of Mann-Whitney U calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, proof-explanation

Brief example of Mann-Whitney U statistic. Imagine of having an series of `A`s and `B`s, e.g.:

```
A B A A B
```

This could represent the results of a race, where a member of Team A got the best result, a member of Team B second best, a member of Team A third best and so on. For this particular statistic, order is descendig, like so:

```
A B A A B
5 4 3 2 1 <-- worst result, 1 point
^
|
+----- best result, 5 points
```

U is then calculated as the number of wins in pairwise contests of members of Team A against Team B.
In this case, A-who-got-1st place beats 2 `B`s, and `A`s in 3rd and 4th position beat a single B respectively; hence the U statistic is 4.

Now, [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Calculations) introduces a second, much quicker method:

$$
{\displaystyle U_{A}=R_{A}-{n_{A}(n_{A}+1) \over 2}\,\!}
$$

Where $R_A$ is the sum of the ranks of $A$ (5+3+2=10) and $n_A$ is the size of $A$ (3). In this case:

$$
U_{A}= 10 - 6 = 4
$$

What is the way of deriving the quicker formula? I tried to pick up pencil and paper but failed, and each book on google books (plus the original paper) just writes it without any note/demonstration, as if it were obvious to even the most naive reader.

I suspect combinatorics is involved, but I cannot understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_1<\cdots< A_{n_A}$ be the 'scores' of the $n_A$ members of team $A$, ordered from worst (lowest rank) to best (highest rank), and $B_1<\cdots<B_{n_B}$ be the scores of the $n_B$ members of team $B$, also ordered from worst to best.

One way to compute the rank of a given member of team $A$ is to take that member's rank *within* team $A$, and add the number of members of team $B$ who scored worse. For example the worst team member has score $A_1$ and has rank $1$ within team $A$, and we boost this within-$A$ rank by adding the number of  members in team $B$ who performed worse. If nobody in team $B$ did worse, then the rank stays at $1$. If one person in team $B$ did worse, then the rank increases to $2$, and so on.

Summing over each member of team $A$ gives the total sum of ranks of members of $A$:
$$
R_A = \sum_{i=1}^{n_A} \left( i + \sum_{j=1}^{n_B} I(B_j < A_i) \right)
$$
which simplifies
to
$$
R_A=\sum_{i=1}^{n_A}  i + \sum_{i=1}^{n_A}\sum_{j=1}^{n_B} I(B_j<A_i)
=\frac{n_A(n_A+1)}2 + U_A
$$
since the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n_A}\sum_{j=1}^{n_B} I(B_j<A_i)$ is precisely the number of pairwise contests between $A$ and $B$ in which the $A$ member beats the $B$ member.

Comment: Ah! That was  clever. I guess I would like to know how you got the intuition, but I suppose those are things that cannot be teached.

Comment: @tofregato This was my thought process: When I read "the number of pairwise contests in which $A_i$ beats $B_j$" I think of the double sum $\sum_i\sum_j I(B_j<A_i)$; and the expression $n_A(n_A +1)/2$ is exactly the sum of integers $1,\ldots, n_A$. The tricky part is coming up with a story to explain why these two add up to $R_A$ :)