# Proof that Mann-Whitney is just translated sum of ranks

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

## Setup

Given the iid random sample $X_1,...,X_m$ with ranks $Q_1,...,Q_m$ and the iid random sample, $Y_1,...,Y_n$ with ranks $R_1,...,R_n$. Then the sum of ranks is,
\begin{align}
W = \sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i
\end{align}
Given the indicator function $\psi$ which is 1 when the parameter is positive, and zero otherwise. The Mann Whitney test is,
\begin{align}
 U = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \psi(Y_j-X_i)
\end{align}

## Question

Show that $$W = U + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

## Solution

Well I recognize that,
\begin{align}
  \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align}
Qualitatively, $U$ is the sum of the number of times that each $Y_i$ is greater than $X_i$.

I tried to make a summation like,
\begin{align}
W &=  \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \psi(Y_j-X_i) + \sum_{j=1}^n j\\
 &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n\left[\psi(Y_j-X_i) + j \right]
\end{align}
leading nowhere. What I really want is some sort of summation to rewrite,
\begin{align}
W = \sum_{i=1}^n R_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} i (\text{if } Z_i \text{ is } X_i) ...
\end{align}

Seems like a simple problem, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See this explanation, which uses slightly different notation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3668777/215011

Comment: @grand_chat Thank you I think this totally helps